# error with CGImageCreateWithImageProvider

Tags: iphone, ios4, cgimage

I'm use rendering in `drawRect`, but first time I always get error:

> < Error >: CGImageCreateWithImageProvider: invalid image size: `768 x 768`.

I draw image with dimensions `768x500`.
First time image don't draw into context, but next times it is draws.

What is it ?

Comment: I have the same problem, only it's complaining about `0 x 0` even though my images aren't 0 x 0.

Comment: I have the same problem when running on device. On simulator it works.

<Error>: CGImageCreateWithImageProvider: invalid image size: 32 x 32.